# Compile wcecompat to a dll

Tags: c, windows, open-source, makefile

I am using wcecompat to bridge the gap between WinCE SDK and OpenSSL. Due to LGPL license issue, I want to compile it to a dynamically linked library. Here is part of the makefile (full file is at https://github.com/mauricek/wcecompat/blob/master/makefile). My question is, how to modify it to build a dll instead of a static lib?

```
all: lib\wcecompat.lib lib\wcecompatex.lib

echo $(OBJS)

obj:
@md obj 2> NUL

lib:
@md lib 2> NUL

$(OBJS): makefile obj


lib\wcecompat.lib: lib $(OBJS) makefile
@lib /nologo /out:lib\wcecompat.lib $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS)

lib\wcecompatex.lib: lib $(OBJS) makefile
@lib /nologo /out:lib\wcecompatex.lib $(OB
```

JS)

Answer (score 1):

Use `link` (i.e. link.exe) instead of `lib` for the two targets:

```
lib\wcecompat.lib: lib $(OBJS) makefile
    @lib /nologo /out:lib\wcecompat.lib $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS)

lib\wcecompatex.lib: lib $(OBJS) makefile
    @lib /nologo /out:lib\wcecompatex.lib $(OBJS)
```

... and rename the targets to `wcecompat.dll` and `wcecompatex.dll` respectively.

However, this will indeed only help you to build the DLL, it does not cover any modifications to export the functions you may need from that DLL. Also remember that DLLs with Code have a DllMain function as entry point (though it's not exported as such).

Comment: I put a bounty on this for a co-worker, but they were not available to verify, but better you get the bounty than nobody ; ) thanx for the help!